# Antlr4 - parse right to left instead left to right

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

Suppose I have the following antlr rule:

```
statement      : variableDeclaration
               | printStatement
               | functionCall
               | returnStatement ;

returnStatement : 'return' ;

//other rules
```

And the some code as follows

```
fun() {
   return 5;
}
```

The way antlr parses the line is left to right, which in most cases expected.

I would however like to first get callback from parser for `5` and the for `return`. It means right to left parsing.

Is it possible? If yes, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

[ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/papers/LL-star-PLDI11.pdf) is a [LL(*) parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser) generator and *parses the input from **L**eft to right, performing [**L**eftmost derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Derivations_and_syntax_trees) of the sentence.*